# Mongo: Ensuring latest nested attribute has a value between given arguments

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection 'books'. Here's a typical book:

```
BOOK

name: 'Test Book'
author: 'Joe Bloggs'
print_runs: [
  {publisher: 'OUP', year: 1981},
  {publisher: 'Penguin', year: 1987},
  {publisher: 'Harper-Collins', year: 1992}
]
```

I'd like to be able to filter books to return only books whose *last* print run was after a given date, and/or before a given date...and I've been struggling to find a feasible query. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Is `print_runs` really an array? Is "last print run" defined as the most recent `year`, or last index in the (likely) array?

Comment: Hi wired - thanks for the response. print_runs is an array, and yes - the last entry will always have the latest year

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options, as getting access to the "last" element in the array and only filtering on that is difficult/impossible with the normal `find` options in MongoDB queries. (Unfortunately, you can't `$slice` with `find`).

1. Store the most recent published `publisher` and `year` in the `print_runs` array *and* in a special (denormalized/copy) of the data directly on the book object. `Book.last_published_by` and `Book.last_published_date` for example. Queries would be simple and super fast.
2. MapReduce. This would be simple enough to emit the last element in the array and then "reduce" it to just that. You'd need to do incremental updates on the MapReduce to keep it accurate.
3. Write a relatively complex aggregation framework expression

The aggregation might look like:

```
db.so.aggregate({ $project :
    { _id: 1, "print_run_year" : "$print_runs.year" }}, 
    { $unwind: "$print_run_year" }, 
    { $group : { _id : "$_id", "newest" : { $max : "$print_run_year" }}}, 
    { $match : { "newest" : { $gt : 1991, $lt: 2000 } }
})
```

As it may require a bit of explanation:

- It projects and unwinds the year of the print runs for each book.
- Then, group on the `_id` (of the book, and create a new computed field called, `newest` which contains the highest print run year (from the projection).
- Then, filter on `newest` using a `$gt` and `$lt`

I'd suggest option #1 above would be the best from an efficiency perspective, followed by the MapReduce, and then a distant third, option #3.

Comment: If you dont mind, can you please include map-reduce solution as well?

Comment: Awesome answer @WiredPrairie !
i was not aware we can add new property to document in $project pipeline itself. Good example :) +UpVote